# Vue.js vuetify how to play a sound clip

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have to convert my Vue.js project to vuetify framework. What worked in my Vue.js project is

```html
<audio controls id="myVideo" autoplay loop  hidden>
                <source src="src/assets/clock.mp3" type="audio/wav">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
```

But this same code doesn't work in the vuetify project

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12>
                <audio controls id="myVideo" autoplay loop  hidden>
                <source src="src/assets/clock.mp3" type="audio/wav">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-title>
                        Question paper
                    </v-card-title>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

What could be the possible reason for that?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated HTML code in the dev tools? Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Probably related to the format. You offer mp3, but the meta description points to wav.